# non-static template member : possible?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, non-static, template-variables

Is it possible to create non-static template field in a class?
If no, how to workaround?

Such fields should be created at compile time as needed.

### Example

I have a lot of `B`-class, like `B1`,`B2`,`B3`.
*(In real case, they have more meaningful names.)*

I want to create a class `D` that has **non-static** template function `add<BX>()` that have to `counter++` every time I call it, for each individual `BX`, for a certain instance of D.
*(In real case, it does somethings more complex.)*

Here is a working [**demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9110f4b10295baf5) to achieve it.
Sadly, I currently have to hard-code every `BX`, one-by-one (`B1`,`B2`,`B3`) inside `D` :-

```
class B1{};class B2{};class B3{};
class Counter{
    public: int counter=0;
};
template<class BX>class Tag{};
class D{
    Counter countB1;
    Counter countB2;
    Counter countB3;
    public: template<class BX> void add(){  
        add_(Tag<BX>());
    }
    private:
    void add_(Tag<B1>){ countB1.counter++;}
    void add_(Tag<B2>){ countB2.counter++;}
    void add_(Tag<B3>){ countB3.counter++;}
    public: template<class BX> int get(){
        return get_(Tag<BX>());
    }
    private:
    int get_(Tag<B1>){  return countB1.counter;}
    int get_(Tag<B2>){  return countB2.counter;}
    int get_(Tag<B3>){  return countB3.counter;}
};
```

Here is the usage.  Notice that each instance of `D` keep its own `counter` :-

```
int main() {
    D d1;
    d1.add<B2>();   d1.add<B2>();   d1.add<B3>();
    std::cout<<d1.get<B1>()<<" "<<d1.get<B2>()<<" "<<d1.get<B3>()<<"\n";
    //^ print 0 2 1  
    D d2;
    d2.add<B1>();
    std::cout<<d2.get<B1>()<<" "<<d2.get<B2>()<<" "<<d2.get<B3>()<<"\n";
    //^ print 1 0 0  (not 1 2 1)
    return 0;
}
```

I dream for something like :-

```
class D{
    Counter<BX> countBX; //???
    public: template<class BX> void add(){  
         Counter<BX>::getNonStaticInstance(this).counter++; //???
    }
    public: template<class BX> int get(){
        return Counter<BX>::getNonStaticInstance(this).counter; //???
    }
};
```

I know how to do it if `countBX` is static, but for non-static it seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a <s>`std::map`</s> `std::unordered_map` (suggestion from Yakk; thanks) of indexes and RTTI?

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeindex>

class B1 {};
class B2 {};
class B3 {};

class D
 {
   private:
      std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::size_t> bxMap;

   public:
      template <typename BX>
      void add ()
       { ++ bxMap[std::type_index(typeid(BX))]; }

      template <typename BX>
      int get ()
       { return bxMap[std::type_index(typeid(BX))]; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   D d1;
   d1.add<B2>();    d1.add<B2>();   d1.add<B3>();
   std::cout<<d1.get<B1>()<<" "<<d1.get<B2>()<<" "<<d1.get<B3>()<<"\n";
   //^ print 0 2 1
   D d2;
   d2.add<B1>();
   std::cout<<d2.get<B1>()<<" "<<d2.get<B2>()<<" "<<d2.get<B3>()<<"\n";
   //^ print 1 0 0
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Do you care about the order of that map?

Comment: Yakk - no, I soppose I don't. Do you mean that is better `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: Brilliant RTTI solution!

Comment: It is 2x slower than OP's, though (-O2).   OP's code (~ 60K tick) : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3d9885b523dc9a5    This solution  (~120K tick): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fe76fc73507a306.   It is not bad - I just want to point out.

Comment: @javaLover It does different things than the OP: the OP code handles a fixed collection of types; this handles an unbounded collection of types.  Also note that the operation is trivial (++), while in the "real" case the operation will be more expensive (so the ratio will go down).  And max66, yes, `map` is really `ordered_map`: if you don't need order, consider `unordered_map`.

Comment: @Yakk - thanks; I love C++11 and C++14 but my head is with a C++98 imprinting.

Comment: @javaLover - for slowness, try with `std::unordered_map` as suggested by Yakk; maybe helps; but give also a look at the answer from Leonardo: it seems to me what you wanted (except that you need to explicit the list of `BX` types).

Comment: @AndyG - thanks; but give a look at solution from Leonardo. Simple and elegant (IMHO).

Comment: I tested and found that `std::unordered_map` doesn't help.   I still like your solution most because of high maintainability which is the major concern for this question.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need `RTTI` to solve this problem, nor `std::map`, which are very expensive (specially RTTI). Variadic template and inheritance can solve this for you:

```
class B1 {}; class B2 {}; class B3 {};

template<typename T>
class Counter {
  public:
    int counter = 0;
};

template<class... BXs>
class D : public Counter<BXs>... {
  public:
    template<typename B>
    void add() {
      Counter<B>::counter++;
    }

    template<typename B>
    int get() {
      return Counter<B>::counter;
    }
};
```

Which is very close to what you actually wanted (you were in the right track, by the way).

Comment: It was so simple... very nice and elegant solution.

Comment: Just a note to myself : In this solution, I have to manually put all `BX` in `D` e.g. `D<B1,B2,B3> d1;` kinda similar as AndyG's solution.

Comment: @javaLover unfortunately yes.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately until we get reflection into the standard, there will be no easy way to iterate over members of a class.

Solutions until then either involve implementing reflection yourself (hard and often uses macros which come with their own problems like debuggability) or wrapping up your types into another type (easier).

We can do this with a base class that has a `std::array` of Counters, one for each `BX`:

```
template<class... Bs>
struct Base
{
    std::array<Counter, sizeof...(Bs)> counters;
    // ... more on this later
};
```

Then our `D` class can derive from it and get the counters it needs:

```
struct D :  Base<B1, B2, B3>{ /*...*/};
```

The next thing we'll do is implement an `IndexOf` function in the base class that will allow us to transform a type (one of `B1` `B2` `B3`) into an index.

We can do this with type traits and fold expressions:

```
template<class T>
static constexpr int IndexOf()
{
    // find index of T in Bs...
    int toReturn = 0;
    int index = 0;
    (..., (std::is_same_v<T, Bs> ? toReturn = index : ++index));
    return toReturn;
}
```

And now our `D` class is much simplified and doesn't rely on tag dispatch:

```
struct D :  Base<B1, B2, B3>{   
    template<class BX> 
    void add(){ 
        counters[IndexOf<BX>()].counter++;
    }

    template<class BX> 
    int get(){
        return counters[IndexOf<BX>()].counter;;
    }
};
```

### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ig0bOTgYbasynFN8)

---

### EDIT:

C++14 version of `IndexOf`:

```
template<class T>
static constexpr int IndexOf()
{
    // find index of T in Bs...
    int toReturn = 0;
    int index = 0;
    using swallow = int[];
    (void) swallow {0, (std::is_same<T, Bs>() ? toReturn = index : ++index, 0)...};
    return toReturn;
}
```

### [C++14 Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1a3NtXZ27db7bute)

Comment: You come with the huge demo as always. :)

Comment: @javaLover personally I usually want to jump straight into runnable code when I see a post, so I presume others do, too. I very much enjoyed that your question had that.

Comment: Note this question is tagged C++14.

Comment: @Yakk I missed that. OP's linked example was with C++17