# How does Unity's Object.FindObjectOfType<T>() works?

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, components

In order to create a game engine inspired on Unity3d, I would like to expand this question about how [Unity's GetComponent works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44105058/how-does-unitys-getcomponent-work#) to how Unity's `FindObjectsOfType<T>()` works.

It is expected to return all pointers to objects derived from `<T>` present in the scene.

I know Unity implement it in C++, but how? Objects could be anything in Unity and the Unity's solution is tolerant to inheritance.

The [Unity Description](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) says it is slow, but why? I can imagine it might be array searching using dynamic cast. I am thinking in implementing this functionality using `unordered_multimap`, but it will make the use case of finding for a base class harder.

It doesn't feels right to me making the developer call macros on its implementations. Users must be free to code frictionless.

Another problem is: Who is the owner of the smart pointer taking this into account:

- Object must return find operations as described.
- `GameObject` has its own implementation of `GetComponents<T>()` where Component is an Object too.